# Fuglede's theorem in finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $A$ be normal operator on $V$ and $B$ is an operator such that $AB=BA$. Show that $BA^*=A^*B$.

I guess that this problem should not be so difficult. I have tried different approaches and I got some identities which do not lead to desired equality.

So I would be thankful if you show the solution to this problem, please!

Comment: have you tried explicitly using the commuting polar decomposition from your last post?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611748/commuting-operators-in-polar-decomposition-of-normal-operator

Comment: @user8675309, no to be honest.

Comment: I dont think that it will work.

Comment: I tried to use the previous problem but i failed.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675239/81360)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to think about this problem is when $B$ is diagonalizable, and $A$ being normal is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb C$) so we can call on simultaneous diagonalizability, recognize that being normal $A^*$ may also be simultaneously diagonalized with $B$ (via the same similarity transform that we'd use on $AB$)  which implies that $A^*B = BA^*$.  However it is  conceivable that $B$ might be defective-- so a more direct argument can be employed to compute the norm of the commutator

$\Big\Vert  A^*B - BA^*\big\Vert_F^2$
$=\text{trace}\Big(\big(A^*B - BA^*\big)^*\big(A^*B - BA^*\big)\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(\big(B^*A - AB^*\big)\big(A^*B - BA^*\big)\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(B^*AA^*B\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(AB^*BA^*\Big)- \text{trace}\Big(B^*ABA^*\Big) -\text{trace}\Big(AB^*A^*B\Big) $
$=\text{trace}\Big(AA^*BB^*\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(B^*BA^*A\Big)- \text{trace}\Big(B^*ABA^*\Big) -\text{trace}\Big(BAB^*A^*\Big) $
$=\text{trace}\Big(AA^*BB^*\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(B^*BA^*A\Big) - \text{trace}\Big(B^*BAA^*\Big) -\text{trace}\Big(ABB^*A^*\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(AA^*BB^*\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(B^*BA^*A\Big) - \text{trace}\Big(B^*BAA^*\Big) -\text{trace}\Big(A^*ABB^*\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(AA^*BB^*\Big) + \text{trace}\Big(B^*BA^*A\Big) - \text{trace}\Big(B^*BA^*A\Big) -\text{trace}\Big(AA^*BB^*\Big)$
$=0$

thus by positive definiteness of the (squared) Frobenius norm we have

$\Big\Vert  A^*B - BA^*\big\Vert_F^2 = 0 \longrightarrow A^*B - BA^* = \mathbf 0\longrightarrow A^*B = BA^*$

Comment: I am not so familiar with norm of an operator. Could you explain what is Frobenius norm? And why it can be calculated as a trace? Would be nice if you can give details about that

Comment: Am I right that $\Big\Vert A \Big\Vert_F^2=\Big\Vert C^{-1}AC\Big\Vert_F^2$ where $C$ is non-singular matrix? If its true how to prove it?

Comment: your second question is incorrect, just try a few example.  Your first question... I assume that you know what the 2 norm of a vector is -- the Frobenius norm is the natural generalization of said 2 norm to matrices *if you view matrices as living in a vector space*.  In any case the Frobenius norm is induced by an inner product and easy to work with.   $\mathbf A = 
\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\mathbf a_1 & \mathbf a_2 &\cdots & \mathbf a_{n-1} & \mathbf a_{n}
\end{array}\bigg]$.

Comment: if the norm of operator depends on the basis how are you defining the norm then? Could you give more details, please?

Comment: $\Big \Vert A\Big \Vert_F = \big(\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \vert a_{i,j}\vert^2 \big)^\frac{1}{2} $  $= \big(\sum_{k=1}^n \big \Vert \mathbf a_k\big \Vert_2^2\big)^\frac{1}{2}   $ $=\Big(\text{trace}\big(A^*A\big)\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$.  To be honest I find it extremely hard to believe that you are unfamiliar with the Frobenius norm of a matrix, because you are asking about *normal matrices* and a common way of *defining them* is $\big \Vert \mathbf A \big \Vert_F^{2}   \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \big \vert \lambda_i\big \vert ^2$ and a matrix is normal *iff* that is met with equality (due to Schur)

Comment: it is common to choose an orthonormal basis

Comment: So the norm of operator depends on the basis? I am a bit confused.

Comment: For purposes of this problem --it's actually the other way around -- a matrix is isn't normal under arbitrary change of basis.  Your questions echo this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542129/are-unitary-matrices-still-unitary-under-similarity-transformations/3542169 where unitary matrices are a special case of normal.  To be honest the way 'choice/change of basis' is being used is abusive here... being normal corresponds much more with bilinear forms than linear maps (i.e. effecting congruence transforms instead of similarity transforms).  I think you have some reading to do.

Comment: I guess that I got you reasoning almost completely. Am I right that when you wrote $\text{trace}(B^*AA^*B)=\text{trace}(AA^*BB^*)$ you used that $\text{trace}(CD)=\text{trace}(DC)$, right?

Comment: right.  The idea here is we have 4 matrices and the manipulations allowed are (i) cyclic property of trace, (ii)$AB = BA$, (iii)$B^*A^* = A^*B^*$, (iv) $AA^* = A^*A$... we always have (i) but $\{\text{ii, iii, iv}\}$ are special features of your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got your solution completely! Really nice reasoning!  I realized that Frobenius norm is the norm generated from usual inner product on the space of matrices, i.e. $(A,B):=\text{trace}(A^*B)$. I accept your answer as the best! How did you come up with this?

Comment: another way of characterizing normality of $A$ is $\text{trace}\Big(\big(A^* A\big)^2 \Big) \geq  \text{trace}\Big(\big(A^2\big)^* \big(A^2\big)  \Big)$ with equality *iff* $A$ is normal.  It's a worthwhile exercise to prove this to yourself; (a) one approach is compute $\big \Vert \mathbf A^* \mathbf A - \mathbf {AA}^* \big \Vert_F^2 $ (b) a  nicer approach comes from Cauchy-Schwarz (try it).  For your problem I kept trying to prove the result via use of Cauchy-Schwarz in the spirit of (b) but I hit too many dead ends and decided instead to imitate (a)

Answer (score 0):

This is Fuglede's theorem. From the spectral theorem, $A$ can be written as

$$A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_iP_i,$$

and $A^{*}$ can be expressed similarly by replacing $\lambda_i$ by its conjugate. Now, notice that for $p_i(x)=x\prod_{j : \lambda_j \neq \lambda_i}(x-\lambda_j)$

$$p_i(A)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_i(\lambda_j)P_j=\lambda_i\prod_{j : \lambda_j \neq \lambda_i}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)\sum_{j : \lambda_j=\lambda_i}P_j.$$
(The first equality is a generalization of the fact that $A^k = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^kP_i$.) This implies that
$$\lambda_i\sum_{j : \lambda_j=\lambda_i}P_j=\frac{p_i(A)}{\prod_{j : \lambda_j \neq \lambda_i}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)}.$$
Given that A and B commute, we have that $p_i(A)$ and $B$ also commute. So,
$$\lambda_i\sum_{j : \lambda_j=\lambda_i}BP_j=\lambda_i\sum_{j : \lambda_j=\lambda_i}P_jB,$$
and by replacing $\lambda_i$ with its conjugate and summing over all distinct eigenvalues we get that $BA^{*}=A^{*}B$.

Comment: You applied spectral theorem to $A$. But in my lectures spectral theorem is proved for self-adjoint operators. Our $A$ may not be self-adjoint.

Comment: The spectral theorem applies more generally to normal matrices.